# react.js pass value to child function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a Map with overlays, in react.js:
Inside `render`, I got this:

```
<Map
                    provider={providers.osm}
                    defaultCenter={[22.3402092,91.8124206]}
                    center={[22.3402092,91.8124206]} zoom={this.state.zoom}
                    width={window.innerWidth*.8} height={window.innerHeight*.8}>

                    {
                        this.line()
                    }

                </Map>
```

And my `line` looks like this:

```
    line = ({ mapState: { width, height }, latLngToPixel,  style = { stroke: 'rgb(255,0,0)', strokeWidth: 2 } }) => {

        let coordsArray=this.state.vertex;

        if (coordsArray.length < 2) {
            return null;
        }

        let lines = [];
        let pixel = latLngToPixel(coordsArray[0]);




        for (let i = 1; i < coordsArray.length; i++) {
            let pixel2 = latLngToPixel(coordsArray[i]);
            lines.push(
                <line key={i} x1={pixel[0]} y1={pixel[1]} x2={pixel2[0]} y2={pixel2[1]} style={style} />
            );
            pixel = pixel2;
        }

        return (
            <svg width={width} height={height} style={{ top: 0, left: 0 }}>
                {lines}
            </svg>
        )
    }
```

It says **Cannot read property 'mapState' of undefined**, how can I resolve this?

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-dawn-cs943?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

## You don't pass arguments to this.line so mapState will always be undefined

In this line `({ mapState: { width, height },` you are destructuring the mapState from the argument. Since you don't pass anything to `this.line()` it will always be undefined.

To pass props to `this.line()` just add what ever arguments you want in the brackets `this.line(this.props)`.

But passing the props from the Map to the line is not possible unless map has some hidden context you can check.

Comment: here is my codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-dawn-cs943?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark